# What is meant by 'holiday' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the following sentence:

**If I *won a holiday* anywhere in the world, I would go to Japan.**

Does 'holiday' simply means 'holiday', or does it mean a 'trip' or 'journey' or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it means a trip to a place where you can spend your free  time (a holiday):

Here is a real example:

> [Win a holiday to New York City - Terms and Conditions](https://www.heart.co.uk/terms-conditions/win-new-york-city-terms-and-conditions/)

Answer (score 2):

In American and British English, one meaning of 'holiday' is "a day of festivity or recreation when no work is done": Christmas is a public holiday in many countries, and in British English it can also be used (singular 'holiday' or plural 'holidays') to mean the same as the American "vacation" - "an extended period of leisure and recreation, especially one spent away from home or in travelling": I had a holiday in China last year.

[Holiday (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/holiday)